# Configure avrdude for programming with a ft232r cable

Tags: ftdi, avrdude, isp

I bought a ftdi cable with the following pins.

1. Vcc
2. GND
3. RX
4. TX
5. RTS
6. CTS

It's possible to use this device to upload code to an ATmega328p using the avrdude utility?

When I run this line on linux terminal:

```
sudo avrdude -c ft232r -p ATMEGA328P -P "/dev/ttyUSB0" -b 57600 -U flash:w:led.hex
```

I get this output:

```
avrdude: invalid portname '/dev/ttyUSB0': use 'ft[0-9]+'
```

I know that some ft232r boards can be used for this purpose, but all of them that I've seen until now rely on the DTR pin, which I don't have access.

Comment: Are you trying to do ISP, or to talk to a bootloader? Your current command is an unworkable mix of the two, and you will need to make it definitively one or the other.

Comment: I'm trying to do a ISP, could please explain better how I'm making a mix of the two?

Comment: You're using a USB serial address only suitable for bootloader and other runtime communication, mixed up with an ISP command.

Comment: Yes I see that, @C_Elegans and Janka have already alerted me about that problem. I'm working on this, please see the C_Elegans answer and comments to understand what I've done so far. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://make.kosakalab.com/arduino/bootloader/index_en.html) guide, you can modify your avrdude.conf to use a different pin for the reset signal than normal. So you would want to add the following to your avrdude.conf

```
programmer
  id    = "ft232r_mod";
  desc  = "FT232R Synchronous BitBang";
  type  = "ftdi_syncbb";
  connection_type = usb;
  miso  = 1;  # RxD
  sck   = 0;  # RTS
  mosi  = 2;  # TxD
  reset = 3;  # CTS
;
```

and invoke avrdude as `avrdude -c ft232r_mod -p m328p -P ft0 -U flash:w:led.hex` (making sure to use ft0 instead of the serial port name). Alternatively, if you post what your FTDI board is, there may be an exposed pad for the DTR signal, like on Adafruit's [FTDI Friend](https://learn.adafruit.com/ftdi-friend/programming-blank-avrs). Finally if neither of those work, and you have a working arduino, [you can use it as an isp](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP).

Comment: Hello @C_Elegans I did what you suggest: `sudo avrdude -c ft232r_mod -p ATMEGA328P -P ft0 -b 57600 -U flash:w:led.hex`

But when I hit enter, nothing happens. It's like the avrdude has entered in an infinite loop. I suspected it could be a connection issue and try to swap the MOSI and MISO wires but avrdude didn't change this odd behavior.

Comment: I also have already uploaded a blinky code in the chip and expected the device to be reseted before the burning process started, but it continues to run like nothing its happening. I manually grounded 328p's resest pin, but didn't work either.

Comment: Hmm. What happens if you remove the `-U flash:w:led.hex`?

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: So what is the current output of avrdude?

Comment: I press 'enter' and I see just the terminal cursor blinking. The avrdude gives no output.

Comment: From what you said it sounds like avrdude isn't communicating with the ftdi cable. Can you post what model you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Avrdude needs to employ libftdi to get better control on the individual port lines of the adapter. Instead of `/dev/ttyUSB0`, it wants to read `ft0` for the first FTDI interface.